# Delete Completely from MS Access Database and Gridview Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I can able to delete the selected row in gridview temporary, when I open again same Form it displays all rows again using this code

```
gridview1.DeleteselectedRows();
```

But I need to delete completely from Database also, So I tried this code but this code deleted  next row of selected row or previous row of selected row from gridview. What was wrong in this code ?

```
gridview1.DeleteselectedRows();                                                         object temp = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("InvoiceNumber");

validateDept.InitializeConnection();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(validateDept.connetionString);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand delete1 = new OleDbCommand("delete from NewInvoice_1 where InvoiceNumber=" + temp, con);
OleDbCommand delete2 = new OleDbCommand("delete from NewInvoice_2 where InvoiceNumber=" + temp, con);
delete1 .ExecuteNonQuery();
delete2 .ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure, that your temp object is a string with right value of InvoiceNumber?

Comment: yes it getting right value but small correction in code i updated now

Comment: Is your gridview1.DeleteselectedRows() is done firstly then delete commands? If yes, it remove that row you want to be focused and move focus to next row

Comment: yeah I did that only now I got thank you

Comment: It is possible to add this `gridview1.DeleteselectedRows();` line after close connection ? Is it work fine ?

Comment: I think it possible.  How you bind data to grid? with DataTable? Try to do nothing just to delete rows in grid and save DataSet

Comment: I bind in properties not in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validateDept.InitializeConnection();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(validateDept.connetionString);
con.Open();
OleDbCommand delete1 = new OleDbCommand("delete from NewInvoice_1 where InvoiceNumber=" +        temp, con); 
OleDbCommand delete2 = new OleDbCommand("delete from NewInvoice_2 where InvoiceNumber=" + temp, con);
delete1 .ExecuteNonQuery();
delete2 .ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

dont write `gridview1.DeleteselectedRows();` this line first because it delete selected row from gridview & jumps to next row then database will delete next row, so problem occurs.